# .htaccess rewrite for orphaned URLs containing underscores and arguments

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

I only modify the .htaccess with great care for the purposes of my online store.

Some time ago, I did a website migration from osCommerce to OpenCart. This resulted in orphaned osCommerce-style URLs with these two example formats:

`http://www.londonpower.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=75`

`http://www.londonpower.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=15&products_id=75`

Lots of websites in internet-land have links to my old-style URLs, and I have about 100 of them, so I would like to redirect them to new URLs with the following format:

`http://www.londonpower.com/2-channel-guitar-preamp`

If I understand correctly, the problem has two parts:

1. to eliminate the underscores, as they baffle the .htaccess engine;
2. to then perform a 301 redirect on the URL.

So far, I have been able to get the first underscore to change to a hyphen, with this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

...but no luck with the second underscore (the one that is part of the query string after the "?"). I am stuck there.

Comment: You say you made a change which solved part of your problem. Where is that code? Click on the edit button and add it to your question. It will help you attract responses. Explain what you are stuck on if possible.

Comment: Thank you - I added the info to my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using rewriting for this. Does the file `catalog/product_info.php` exist in the new store? If not, create it and add a simple redirection using a map of old IDs to new URLs. If so, do the same thing in a different file, like `old-redirector.php` then rewrite requests to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, if I am understanding this challenge correctly, a simple redirection won't work because of the underscores. Also, in the last couple of days I've learned that the presence of a query in the original URLs prevents a simple redirection from working (everything after the "?" is ignored). Any advice?